# Remove the RT prio of a process

Tags: linux, process, real-time

I am using a RT-kernel and there are many processes running with RT prio which are not relevant for my use. So I need to unset their RT prio to make them run as normal processes

chrt options do not seem to allow this, as well as renicing..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it on my own thanks to the option -o of chrt

chrt -p -o 0 [$pid]